# Include administrator in author list

Tags: php, admin, user-roles, list-authors

I have this code that is displaying my last active authors. I also would like it to display WP administrators in this list. The code is:

```
$authors =  array();
$count = 0;
$args=array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'caller_get_posts'=> 1
);
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '';
    while ($my_query->have_posts() && $count < 15) : $my_query->the_post();
        $author_id=$my_query->post->post_author;
        $user = new WP_User( $author_id );
        if ( !empty( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) && in_array('contributor',$user->roles) ) {
            if (!in_array($author_id,$authors)) {
                echo '<div class="person">';
```

Where it says `&& in_array('contributor',$user->roles)`, I need to include 'administrator' as well. What would be the right way to put this in? I have tried a lot of things but then the PHP won't work.

Comment: change `in_array('contributor',$user->roles)` to `(in_array('contributor',$user->roles) || in_array('administrator',$user->roles))`

Answer (score 0):

change `in_array('contributor',$user->roles)` to `(in_array('contributor',$user->roles) || in_array('administrator',$user->roles))`